# Android App stops after TextView text is changed

Tags: android, textview, settext, thread-sleep

I have made an android app, which has two **TextView**s. When I change the text using `setText()` then the app stops.
I have read other answers on **StackOverflow** and have implemented them in my program, but the problem still persists.

Here is my `onCreate()` code:

```
TextView ec, vc;
Thread t;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ec = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ce);
    vc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cv);
    t = new Thread(new Runnable() {@Override public void run() {loop();}});
    t.start();
}
```

Here is my `loop()` code:

```
public void loop()
{
    try{Thread.sleep(7000);}catch(Exception e){}
    ec.setText("");
    vc.setText("");
    try{Thread.sleep(53000);}catch(Exception e){}
    t.stop();
}
```

I want to empty the text of both the `TextView`s after 7 seconds.
But when I run my app, after 7 seconds, it stops.

Other answers on **StackOverflow** say that I should put `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` before I initiate the `ec` and `vc` variables. It is already there, but still the app stops.

Please help me.

Comment: Don't do Thread.sleep on Main UI Thread.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with AsyncTasks and get rid of the sleep thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [View.postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) method to run a `Runnable` on the UIThread after a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

UI Elements can only be changed from the UI (Main) thread, therefore it breaks down. Try using:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            //Do something on UiThread
        }
    });
```

But you'll make the UI thread sleep, which means it'll freeze up any way. So, bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
public void loop() 
{ 
    try{Thread.sleep(7000);}catch(Exception e){}
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { 
           ec.setText(""); 
           vc.setText("");  
        } 
    }); 

    try{Thread.sleep(53000);}catch(Exception e){}
    t.stop(); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry. The app still stops.